# How do I make this button interact with my SQL database?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, web

I am currently coding a website with html and c# (asp.net). I have a button that is meant to add one (like a counter) to a value in my SQL database when a user presses it, however when I try this nothing happens? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sjaddone();
}

void sjaddone()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        // if it is closed the program will open it
        con.Open();
    }

    SqlCommand oot = new SqlCommand("Update [websiteDB].[dbo].[location_master_tbl] Set active_users=active_users+1 Where active_users<@active_users");

    Button1.Visible = false;

    oot.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // oot.Close();
}
```

Comment: Great! would you mind updating the Control how you used? are does the click never works or it works only sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things you can look into.

1. Have you copied the button control from different page? if so then you need to delete and create new button for the page you need.
2. If point 1 is not true then add `CausesValidation="False"` in the control like

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="your_btn" runat="server" Text="Press" OnClick="your_btn_Click" CausesValidation="False"/>
   ```
3. Check the `AutoPostBack` value too where you have used the control.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick?view=netframework-4.8) reference may help you.

**UPDATE**:

You should have `OnClick` on your control. I don't see that in your code.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

to be precise with your code, it should look something like:

```
<asp:Button ID="yourBtn" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: Great! would you mind updating the Control how you used? are does the click never works or it works only sometimes?

Comment: thanks for the reply, 
I didn't copy the button control from a different page,
I've tried adding CausesValidation="False" but it unfortunately hasn't made a difference,
I'm going to try your third option now, but I don't understand it very well haha

Comment: The click just refreshes the page and does nothing every time? :(

Comment: No problem lets figure this out, show the control how you used in aspx level.

Comment: ' <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="I'm an active user" Width="150px" Visible="True" CausesValidation="False"/> ' this?

Comment: looks like you don't have `OnClick` property used in your code, I just updated my code, verify and let me know.

Comment: I think I've done what you mean
'
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(this.sjaddone);
'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209551/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-morgan-keilty).